# Can't set content type when uploading to Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, jquery-file-upload

I'm attempting to set the content type of a file when uploading to s3 directory with jQuery and Rails. I've successfully implemented [Ryan Bate's solution](http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3?view=asciicast) without issue.

The problem is the content type does not get set and defaults to `binary/octet-stream`. I've added into Ryan's solution the following:

**uploader_helper.rb**

```
def fields
  {
    # ...
    :content_type => nil,
    # ...
  }
end
```

**paintings.js.coffee**

```
$("#fileupload").fileupload
  add: (e, data) ->
    # ...
    if types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)
      # ...
      data.form.find('#content_type').attr('name','Content-Type')
      data.form.find('#content_type').val(file.type)
      data.submit()
    # ...
```

In addition, my CORS config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I receive a `403 (Forbidden)` error when I try adding these fields.

I've tried adding a bucket policy, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [Ryan's tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3), a policy on content type needs to be added to the [`policy_data`](https://github.com/railscasts/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3/blob/master/gallery-jquery-fileupload/app/helpers/upload_helper.rb#L60-71) method.

For example, if we want to allow any content-type, then this line should be added:

```
["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""]
```